# Difference between a Notice Board and a Bulletin Board?

Tags: differences

Can anyone please help me with this?

Are the two words have the same meaning or they're different?

Comment: A [**bulletin board**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/bulletin_board) is an electronic medium where users can post messages. In North America it is also used to mean a [**pinboard**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/pinboard).

Comment: @WeatherVane's link for 'bulletin board' gives 'noticeboard' as the second definition, so, yes, they _do_ (not are) have the same meaning.

Comment: But as usual not interchangeable in all contexts.